# Unable to install package after publishing it to github as public

Tags: github, npm, installation, package, publish

I've been trying to publish my first package and I managed to do that, it can be found here: https://github.com/WingsDevelopment/export-poc3/packages/1370199
It is public package and github gives me this command npm install @wingsdevelopment/export-poc3@0.0.1 for installation, but when I run it,throws error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@wingsdevelopment%2fexport-poc3 - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@wingsdevelopment/export-poc3@0.0.1' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-18T11_52_02_990Z-debug.log
```

Btw I was following this steps: https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library-2oe

Comment: I also have the same issue with my package

Comment: I did manage to make it work, for me it was that github gave me wrong command for install. Im not sure how I managed to fix it, i think i just removed version from command or something like that..